# Is it possible to access the creator of a class instance?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

What I want to do (and I have high doubts about the possibility of this) is access the creator of a class from within the constructor of that class (without parsing a reference to it).

As an example, take this document class:

```
package
{
    import flash.display.MovieClip;

    public class DocumentClass extends MovieClip
    {
        public function DocumentClass()
        {
            var thing:Thing = new Thing();
        }
    }
}
```

And then `Thing`:

```
package
{
    public class Thing extends Object
    {
        public function Thing()
        {
            // trace DocumentClass as the creator
        }
    }
}
```

Is this possible? If not - is it possible to access the caller of a function? For example I could replace the constructor of `Thing` with `init()` and access `DocumentClass` as the caller of `init()`.

Comment: I am afraid it is not possible in any programming language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There used to be `arguments.caller` but when you use that, you get this warning:

> 1058: Migration issue: The property
>   caller is no longer supported.  Try
>   declaring caller as an argument of the
>   function instead..

So I think you'll have to pass it yourself after all.